# Yeoman CLI tool enforce default options

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, yo

I'm using yeoman cli tool to install a custom generator, I would like to call it from a gui application where the user could choose option using a window with some options.

I want to pass this options colect from windows and pass this to the yeoman CLI in order to not having interation between the command line and the user.  Or a second options in run the generation without any options forcing the generator to assume all the default values.

Who I can achive that? I'm finding for a flag to force the default value or a way to passing answers from a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovery this tool that allow us run the yeoman generator in silent mode, you could define your answers in a configuration file.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/yeoman-gen-run